# Variable declaration with const and reference

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

I am confused about variable declarations with references. I read some pages and that made me more confused so preferred to ask here.

I was asked 4 questions in a C++ interview; which one of them is wrong and why?

```
(1) int & n;
(2) const int & n=15;
(3) float x; const int & n =x;
```

Could some one please explain which in incorrect and why?

Comment: What does your compiler tell you?

Comment: `c++ interview(which is same in c i guess)` Sounds like someone was in over their head.

Comment: The  Compiler do not give answer of Why ? (but it's ok if you really do not want to help then you will surely comment like this)

Comment: @user3735822, my compiler gives a pretty clear explanation of *Why*. What does yours say?

Comment: http://ideone.com/70GBig is that not clear? (scroll down to compilation info and ignore the warnings)

Comment: I find it hard to imagine anyone asking that question from someone they were looking to employ to write their software. Or is someone interviewing people to do their homework for them? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr References must be initialised on declaration (either directly or in the class initialisation).

```
int& n;
```

This leaves the reference `n` uninitialised. References must be initialised on declaration.

```
const int& n = 15;
```

Nothing wrong here. The reference to a `const int` is initialised to `15`.

```
float x; const int& n = x;
```

The `float` is ok, but a bad idea to be left uninitialised. The reference `n` being initialised to `x` (float/integral conversions apply), it's not a great idea either.

Comment: but why do not it give error for flotavariable intialised to int n as reference ? (does it do any type casting ?)

Comment: @user3735822. Floating - integral conversions would apply. I'm wouldn't recommend writing code like this in a general sense. But the code looks correct and hence will compile with no errors. Additional note: a `const&` will bind to a temporary object and extend the life of the temporary object.

Comment: @user3735822. If you remove the `const` in `const int& n = x` to `int& n = x` (for the `float` case); you will get a compilation error.

Comment: @user3735822 `int& n;` would be OK in a class definition. It all depends on context. I'm sure that would have got you bonus points in the interview.

Comment: @juanchopanza could you please give me situation where  int& n; is working without error.

Comment: @juanchopanza but you have not used "n" anywhere in your code.

Comment: @user3735822 Yes I have. Are you blind? Do you see the structure called `Foo`?

Comment: i am talking  to use "n" in main() . How you will access that n in main() ?

Comment: @Niall sorry for the disturbance that was for him and also thanks for answer.

Answer (score 2):

A reference must always be initialized.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't necessarily make `int & n;` wrong. It would be a valid member of a struct, for example, when it would be initialised along with the rest of the struct.

Comment: @Jens THANKS FOR THE ANSWER BUT I WONDER THAT WHY IT DO NOT GIVE ERROR FOR DATA TYPE CHNAGED FROM FLOAT TO INt on intialisation in  (3) float x; const int & n =x;

Comment: @hvd As long it is initialized along with the rest of the struct, it is always initialized. When you do not initialize it in the constructor, you will get a compiler error.

Comment: @Jens Right. So your answer that a reference must always be initialized doesn't necessarily apply to any of the three fragments in the question. It's a likely intended answer for the first fragment, but if so, that just means the question is wrong.

Comment: @hvd Why does it not apply to the first fragment. The question was which one of the three fragments is wrong, and that would be the first one for the given reason.

Comment: @hvd Forget my last comment. The question is missing necessary context.